# What happened to the ido-imenu in ruby-mode function in Emacs24?

Tags: emacs, emacs24, ido, ruby-mode

[Emacs 23.2](https://github.com/technomancy/emacs-starter-kit/) in emacs-starter-kit v1 has `C-x C-i` (or `ido-imenu`) (similar to Sublime Text's Cmd+R). [Emacs24](http://technomancy.us/153) in emacs-starter-kit v2 lacks this function. I found [this github issue](https://github.com/eschulte/emacs24-starter-kit/issues/15) and [a fix](http://eschulte.me/emacs-starter-kit/starter-kit-defuns.html), which try to recreate the functionality. While this `ido-imenu` works in `elisp-mode`, it stopped working in `ruby-mode`. I get:

```
imenu--make-index-alist: No items suitable for an index found in this buffer
```

1. Has anyone figured out how to get this to work?
2. Why was this taken out of Emacs24?
3. Is there a new replacement for this function?

Comment: Emacs + emacs-starter-kit != Emacs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I finally figured it out, after reading the [**Defining an Imenu Menu for a Mode** section](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/ImenuMode#toc8) on emacs-wiki again.

**Short answer**: you need to add this bit to your customization. Feel free to add more *types* to the list (I am happy with just methods).

```
(add-hook 'ruby-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (set (make-local-variable imenu-generic-expression)
                 '(("Methods"  "^\\( *\\(def\\) +.+\\)"          1)
                   ))))
```

**Longer answer**: I first tried to define a `ruby-imenu-generic-expression` function and set that to `imenu-generic-expression` by using the `ruby-mode-hook`:

```
(defvar ruby-imenu-generic-expression
  '(("Methods"  "^\\( *\\(def\\) +.+\\)"          1))
  "The imenu regex to parse an outline of the ruby file")

(defun ruby-set-imenu-generic-expression ()
  (make-local-variable 'imenu-generic-expression)
  (make-local-variable 'imenu-create-index-function)
  (setq imenu-create-index-function 'imenu-default-create-index-function)
  (setq imenu-generic-expression ruby-imenu-generic-expression))

(add-hook 'ruby-mode-hook 'ruby-set-imenu-generic-expression)
```

This however did not work (I would get the same error as before). More reading of the [**Defining an Imenu Menu for a Mode** section](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/ImenuMode#toc8) showed me the way. Now, I'm not an `elisp` expert, so here's my hypothesis: basically, the above method works for modes where the

> major mode supports a buffer local copy of the “real” variable, ‘imenu-generic-expression’. If your mode doesn’t do it, you will have to rely on a hook.

The example for `foo-mode` made it clear how to do it for `ruby-mode`. So it appears that `ruby-mode` does not have a buffer-local copy of the real `imenu-generic-expression` variable. I still can't explain why it worked in Emacs 23.2 (with ESK v1) but does not on Emacs24, but hey at least I found a working solution.

Answer (score 4):

Since the function is part of ESK (as opposed to something budled with Emacs) you'd probably do best to report the bug upstream. On a related note ESK main competitor Emacs Prelude offers the same functionality (bound to <kbd>C-c i</kbd> by default) and it seems to be working fine with ruby-mode in Emacs 24. [Here](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/ImenuMode#toc10) you can find more on `ido-imenu`.

Comment: The [ESK github issue](https://github.com/eschulte/emacs24-starter-kit/issues/15) I linked to in my question states that ido-imenu was not part of ESK. More googling suggested that it was part Emacs 23 but removed in Emacs 24.

That's why I asked this question.

Comment: Thanks. Eventually reading more and more into the link you provided, led me to the answer.